# Plotting multiple graphs does not work using pylab

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter

I want to visualize the [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) with different `n`. My aim is to plot multiple graphs in the same figure but it does not work. It only plots the last graph and ignores the others. I am using the Jupyter Notebook. 
This is my Code:

```
from decimal import Decimal

def calc_p_distinct(n):
    p_distinct = numpy.arange(0, n.size, dtype=Decimal)
    for i in n:
        p_distinct[i] = Decimal(1.0)

    for i in n:
        for person in range(i):
            p_distinct[i] = Decimal(p_distinct[i]) * Decimal(((Decimal(365-person))/Decimal(365)))

    return p_distinct


# n is the number of people
n = numpy.arange(0, 20)
n2 = numpy.arange(0, 50)
n3 = numpy.arange(0, 100)

# plot the probability distribution
p_distinct = calc_p_distinct(n)
pylab.plot(n, p_distinct, 'r')

p_distinct2 = calc_p_distinct(n2)
pylab.plot(n2, p_distinct2, 'g')

p_distinct3 = calc_p_distinct(n3)
pylab.plot(n3, p_distinct3, 'b')

# set the labels of the axis and title
pylab.xlabel("n", fontsize=18)
pylab.ylabel("probability", fontsize=18)
pylab.title("birthday problem", fontsize=20)

# show grid
pylab.grid(True)

# show the plot
pylab.show()
```

When I replace one of the calc_p_distinct() function calls with another built-in function (e.g. numpy.sin(n)), it will show me two graphs. So, I conclude that it must have something to do with my function. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a problem with `matplotlib`; all the lines are there, just on top of each other (which makes perfect sense; for 100 people, the probability for only the first 20 is the same as for a group of just 20 people).

If I quickly plot them with a different line width:

[image]

Comment: Ahh! My bad, you are absolutly right, maybe it was too late when I did this :D Thank you!